# Como observar a inatividade do usuário e habilitar ou desabilitar a tela de bloqueio no Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

## Como faço para desativar o bloqueio automático da tela no windows phone 8.1 ?

```
 phoneService.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Antes o uso da linha acima atendia, porém o mesmo não e mais válido para a nova versão do Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DisplayRequest.RequestActive
```

Documentação e Exemplo em:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx

Fonte: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654493/194717